# How to read/parse a curve adjustment (*.acv) file with actionscript 3

Tags: flash, parsing, image-processing, actionscript, photoshop

I have a *.acv file created from Photoshop, and I'm having an extremely hard time figuring out how to read or parse this file in flash with AS3.

I have done it before with Objective-C and a framework called GPUImage https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage.  This contains a class called GPUImageACVFile, which you pass the acv file´s path when instantiating it, and it contains arrays with the rgb, red, green, and blue Curve Points, which is what I'm trying to do in flash.

I found this library https://github.com/inspirit/GPUImage, which I thought was a ported version of the Objective-C GPUImage I mentioned above, but I couldn't understand it much.

Upon further research, I found this unanswered question, which bears a similarity to what I am trying to achieve http://forums.adobe.com/thread/869447, unfortunately the responses there are not helpfull.

I can give a acv file example if necessary or if anyone thinks it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.acv is a binary file (I think the format may be described here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/ ).  you can load and read binary files with URLLoader and ByteArray.